# ctrl+f2 keyboard shortcut does not work in VSCode on macOs

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have ctrl+f2 mapped to toggle bookmark in my vscode keyboard shortcuts.

```
{ "key": "ctrl+f2",            "command": "bookmarks.toggle", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
```

It work correctly on Linux and Windows, but not on macOs.

I have enabled the setting to switch function keys (f1, f2, etc) to behave as standard function keys.

I have then unmapped ctrl+f2 in macOs keyboard shortcut settings.

But still ctrl+f2 keyboard shortcut is not registering with vscode.

Answer (score 2):

## Troubleshooting VS-Code Keybinding Issues

---

###### The best way to *troubleshoot* an issue with *Keybindings* in *V.S. Code* is to use the tool that was created for solving keybinding issues

**The tool is simply named: ["Keyboard Shortcut Troubleshooting Tool"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings)**
The tool comes with **V.S. Code** *"out of the box"*, as a result; no downloading, or installation is needed. To use the tool you just activate it from the ***Quick Input Menu***  that drops open by pressing the **`F1`-Key**. If you cannot find it your self I posted instructions below, and an image. If you can find it yourself, then skip the *"Activating the Troubleshooting Tool"* Section, and go ahead and read, *"Effectively Troubleshooting Issues with the Troubleshoot Keyboard-Shortcut Tool"*

#### Activate V.S. Code's Troubleshooting Tool

---

- ###### Hit the `F1`-Key
- ###### When the quick input drops open type the following into the text input:

  - *"Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting"*
  - Select the option: **`Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`**
- ###### It should automatically open the OUTPUT panel, which is located in the same panel that your terminal is. Make sure that the OUTPUT is set to LOG(Window) in the drop down. (I took a picture and posted it below if you can't find the *Keyboard Shortcut Troubleshooter*).

###### *The image might have funny declensions because I am on a dual monitor setup with 1 1080x1920 curved screen and one 1080x720 screen...*. I cropped it to a STD HD 1920 width.

---

[image: JPEG IMAGE: Activating the Keyboard Shortcut Troubleshooting Tool]

###### HELPFUL SIDE NOTE:

---

> *"This tool may be the most verbose program ever written, as far as I can tell, it logs data to the **OUTPUT Console** each & every time you activate a keyboard event. Truth be told, I find this tool to be extremely distracting, and very annoying. Because of this, it is important to note, that even if you switch out of your OUTPUT console to your terminal or something. The *Troubleshooter* is still actively logging to the OUTPUT Console. Make sure when you are finished to turn it off."*

###### Turning off the Keyboard Troubleshooter, requires the same process as turning it on.

---

## Using V.S. Code's Troubleshooter

##### STEP-1: Close VS Code

---

This is not to be confused with *reload* V.S. Code. The only mechanism that VS-Code has for reloading its-self, doesn't provide the same functionality as closing, and reopening V.S. Code. The two are similar, but they are not equal (discussion for another time).

actually stop its process from running by hitting the X in the upper right corner of the title-bar, or hit
**`[Alt + F4]`.

##### Step-2: Reopen V.S. Code W/O Any Extensions

---

Don't worry, you won't have to uninstall anything. You will start V.S. Code from the command-line though. Open up your bash terminal, or Powershell, and enter the following command:

```
$ code --disable-extensions
```

**V.S. Code should start almost immediately**

[If the V.S. Code CLI doesn't open your editor, or this doesn't disable your extensions, you should refer to this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions)

##### Step-3: Start the Keyboard Shortcut Troubleshooter

---

I already explained this step above, so their is no reason to go over it again. Do make sure you have your panel open, and the **OUTPUT** tab is selected. You should see a bunch of logging being output, in the VS-Code output (that is redundant sounding),  logging when you use any keybinding. The drop-down should have **`Log(Window)`** showing, as the current log selected.

#### Step-4: Test Your Keybinding

At this point you can use your keybinding, and get results. They might not be the results that you were hoping for, but the *troubleshooter* should give you details as to what is happening when you use your keyboard shortcut (aka bound-key, aka key-binding).

#### Step-5:

Fix the issue by opening the Keyboards Shortcuts configuration file by opening the quick input, (like I described above for the troubleshooter), and type Keyboard Shortcuts. Their will be two options, one is the default Keybindings that cannot be written too, the other is a configuration file, where you are allowed to overwrite all of the default keybindings if you choose. Look in the default keybinding.json file and make sure the keybinding that you feel is assigned to a certain task, really is assigned to it. Look in the regular `keybindings.json` file, and make sure if anything is written in it, that those keybindings are not affecting the keybinding that is not working for you. Use the information from the troubleshooter to help guide you through the process.

---

##### These links below further elaborate on V.S. Code keybindings:

- ###### [V.S. Code Community Docs (Community Contributed)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings)
- ###### [V.S. Code Official Docs (Keybindings)](https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization/keybindings/)

---

Comment: I know I have to edit this, but I just had an unexpected guest so I will edit it in an hour or two after they leave.